# Allow user post products

Tags: e-commerce, prestashop

I need to know if I can in prestashop or another eccommerce framework allow the users to publish his own products.

I ask this because i need that feature to my site.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ecommerce system has this feature by default. You can have modules for this feature. I am not sure about any module for any e commerce system, but hopefully you will get one if you search using google. If you did not find any, then you have to develop it by some one.